# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite encoding

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, azure-web-app-service

I have following rewrite rule in web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Search" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^search/(.+)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="?q={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works fine both on IIS Express 8.0 and IIS 7.5 on Azure Websites for urls like `/search/test` (only ascii characters) - redirects to `/?q=test`. 
But for urls with unicode characters (`/search/тест` or `/search/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`) on IIS 7.5 on Azure Websites redirects to `/?q=Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚` (or `/?q=%C3%91%E2%80%9A%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91%C2%81%C3%91%E2%80%9A`) instead of `/?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`. It works correctly on IIS Express 8.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the internal `{UrlEncode:{}}` function to properly encode the characters that are invalid in the URL (e.g. UTF-8 characters). So replace the URL part with: `url="?q={UrlEncode:{R:1}}"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it should be `url="?q={UrlEncode:{R:1}}"`. I thought I tried this, but looks like I tried something else.

Comment: For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#string-functions